# Youtube and Vimeo Videos support in Android with Vitamio

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview, vimeo, android-video-player

In my app I am trying to play a Vimeo video using VideoView but that seems out of scope right now and therefore I have decided to first try and get the youtube video work.

I added vitamio plugin and it seems to work fine with mp4 videos that I uploaded on my site over the both 3G and wifi connection however it does not work when I provide a rstp link of youtube to videoview and try to watch it over Wifi.

Do I have to use another technique to make the youtube video work over both WIFI and 3G? Do I need a special URL for it?

If someone also has suggestions on how I can use Vimeo video with Vitamio then that would also be great.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    String SrcPath = "rtsp://v4.cache7.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQky7ThXrRjPYRMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYKjR78WV1ZH5Tgw=/0/0/0/video.3gp"; //this doesnot work over WIFI 
    String SrcPath = "http://myURL.com/videoname.mp4"; //this works over 3G connection but failes on WIFI


    try {
        VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("custom", "Unable to play video");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the above post.....

implemented vimeo video play functionality in android app using web view...here is the link .if you find it suitable.This is working perfectly..

https://github.com/bilthon/VimeoTest..

and for it to work on all devices make sure....to add hardwareaccelaration=true.in your mnifest file.....